# OpenGL ES 2.0 solid colour & colour value precision issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, colors

**Issue partially resolved, leaving previous post & code here for reference, new issue (stated in title) after the strong text at the bottom**

I am trying to use colour picking to identify objects in OpenGL on Android. My code works fine for the most part, all objects are assigned unique colours in a 0.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f format (Alpha is always 0), and when clicking on the objects they are identified (Most of the time) using glreadpixels and converting/comparing the values.

The problem only occurs when using *certain* colour values. For instance, if an object is given the colour 0.0f, 0.77f, 1.0f (RGB), it will not colour solidly. It will colour parts of the object 0.0,0.76,1.0 or 0.0,0.78.1.0. I thought it might be colour blending so I coloured every object in the scene this colour but the same thing happened, this also eliminates any lighting issues which I thought might be another cause (despite not implementing light explicitly to my knowledge). This issue occurs on a few colours, not just the one stated.

How can I tell the object or the renderer to colour these objects solidly exactly as stated, instead of a blend of the colours either side of it?

The colours are not coming through as stated, if a color of R:0.0f G:0.77f B1.0f is passed to glUniform4v & glDrawArrays, it is drawn (and read by glreadpixels) as R:0.0f G:0.78f B1.0f. This is not the only value with which this happens, this is just an example.

Any suggestions for a fix are appreciated

Comment: set alpha to 1 (or 255 if that is your max)?

Comment: I think I tried that but I'll give it a go 1 moment... Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have changed anything at all which is strange

Comment: Can you post your shader code?

Comment: @DanceIgel added it to the main post

Comment: Have you tried to disable dithering? `glDisable(GL_DITHER)`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi That appears to have stopped the different triangles of 1 shape being different colours which is extremely helpful, thank you. However, the shapes are still not the colour requested i.e The region in the example R: 0.0f, G: 0.77f, B: 1.0f  is now coming through as being completely  R: 0.0f, G: 0.78f, B: 1.0f

Comment: It's kind of unfortunate that you changed the question while I was already writing an answer. You obviously didn't know that, but now at least part of my answer does not match the question anymore. I'll just leave it there anyway, even though it looks like I missed the topic of the question now.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I have changed the title and sent an email to your webmaster from your site with further details as I have failed to get this working tonight, please check the email for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two aspects that can come in your way of getting exactly the expected color:

#### Dithering

Dithering for color output is enabled by default. Based on what I've seen, it doesn't typically seem to come into play (or at least not in a measurable way) if you're rendering to targets with 8 bits per component. But it's definitely very noticeable when you're rendering to a lower color depth, like RGB565.

The details of what exactly happens as the result of dithering appears to be very vendor dependent.

Dithering is **enabled** by default. For typical use, that's probably a good thing, because you only care about the visual appearance. And the whole idea of dithering is obviously to enhance the visual quality. But if you rely on getting controllable and predictable values for your output colors, like it's necessary in your picking case, you should always disable dithering:

```
glDisable(GL_DITHER);
```

#### Precision

As you're already aware based on your code, precision is a big concern here. You obviously can't expect to get *exactly* the same floating point value back as the one you originally specified for the color.

The primary loss of precision comes from the conversion of the color value to a normalized value in the color buffer. With 8 bits/component color depth, the precision of that value is 1.0/255.0. Which means that you *should* be fine with generating and comparing values with a precision of 0.01.

Another source of precision loss is the shader processing. Since you specify `mediump` for the precision in the shader code, which gives you at least about 10 bits of precision, that also looks like it should not be harmful.

One possibility is that you didn't actually get a configuration with 8-bit color components. This would also be consistent with the visual dithering effect. Say if you got a RGB565 surface, your observed precision starts to make sense.

For example, with RGB565, if you pass in 0.77 for the green component, the value is multiplied with 63 (2^6 - 1) during fixed point conversion, which gives 48.51. Now, the spec says:

> Values are converted (by rounding to nearest) to a ﬁxed-point value with m bits, where m is the number of bits allocated to the corresponding R, G, B, A, or depth buffer component.

The nearest value for 48.51 is 49. But if you lose *any* kind of precision somewhere on the way, it could very easily become 48.

Now, when these values are converted back to float while you read them back, they are divided by 63.0. If the value in the framebuffer was 48, the result is 0.762, which you would round to in your code 0.76. If it was 49, the result is 0.777, which rounds to 0.78.

So in short:

- Be very careful about what kind of precision you can expect.
- I think you might have an RGB565 framebuffer.

Also, using multiples of 0.01 for the values does not look like an ideal strategy because it does not line up with the representation in the framebuffer. I would use multiples of `2^b - 1`, where `b` is the number of bits in the color components. Use those values when specifying colors, and apply the matching quantization when you compare the values you read back with the expected value.

Comment: Hey Reto, thanks for the explanation, I'm a little awed by your depth of understanding being a simple student myself haha, When you say I should use 2^b-1 for my increments, if we're assuming i am using a 565 framebuffer that would mean 2^5-1 for my first region which is equal to 0.31 is that right? If so, I don't have enough increments to stock all my colours. Would I be alright using 0.031 etc.? If I've misunderstood your answer please correct me

Comment: For 5 bits precision, the increment would be `1 / (2^5 - 1)`, which is `1 / 31`, which is approximately 0.03226.