# Why pixel colour is not accurate in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am using EGLConfig with these specifications:

```
EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 5,
EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 6,
EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 5,
EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, 4,
EGL10.EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 1,
EGL10.EGL_SAMPLES, 4,
```

Shaders:

```
private final static String vertexShaderCode =
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
    "}";

private final static String fragmentShaderCode =
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
    "}";
```

onSurfaceCreated:

```
GLES20.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
// Initialising shapes
```

onDrawFrame:

```
GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
// Drawing shapes
```

Actual problem is that shape colour is not solid and this happens for whole screen area (there are more brighter pixels):
[image]

Real colour is 0.55f, 0.8f, 0.3f.

Comment: This is partly very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204343/opengl-es-2-0-solid-colour-colour-value-precision-issue. But the other question focused more on the actual value of the colors, and the colors being non-uniform was just one aspect of it. So it didn't look close enough for this to be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I saw that question but somehow I missed that it really works when I was testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL performs dithering on the rendering output by default. This is particularly noticeable when the output buffer has a relatively low color depth, like it is the case for RGB565 config your code requests.

To disable dithering, add this call while initializing your OpenGL state, e.g. in `onSurfaceCreated()`:

```
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DITHER);
```

The intention of dithering is of course to improve the visual quality. Unless you have a requirement for the output color to be completely accurate/uniform, leaving dithering enabled may give you better visual results.